# How to create Firebase tables without separating every single field...for security?

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

So I'm delving into Firebase security rules and as far as I understand, rules that are specified higher up in the tree cascade further down into the tree.

So I'm wondering if there's a way to make a case work where I basically have a `/bands` subtree that I want writeable by anyone, however there are `admins` and `members` subtrees where I want only writeable, based on special conditions.

So far, this is kinda what I have going on:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    "bands": {
       "$bandId": {
          ".write": "auth !== null",
          "$bandId": {
            ".write": "auth !== null && data.child('creator_id').val() === auth.uid"
          }
       }
     }
  }
}
```

When I go to test "writing", in the Firebase simulator, something like `/bands/-KnLeIHM4zCspwBZjZP9` where the `creator_id` does NOT match the specified `auth.uid` I have provided, I still get a simulator write success, due to the `/bands` tree-level having the write access.

Is there any clever way to do allow anyone to "push" to `/bands` but then when it gets down to the actual `/bands/$bandId` level, it starts looking at these various conditions? Or am I going to have to rework my data and separate out the trees into even more trees? I have other instances where this kind of thing is necessary, but this is the most succinct version I am working with that I need to solve.

Any thoughts? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{
  "rules": {
    "bands": {
      ".read": "auth != null",
      ".write": "!data.exists() && auth != null",
      "$bandId": {
        ".write": "data.child('creator_id').val() === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

`".write": "!data.exists() && auth != null"` will only allow authenticated users to write to paths within `bands` if they don't exist (creating new content).

Comment: actually, I'm noticing that if I try to do a .push() to `/bands`, I get an error. Is there a way to account for both creating new records on `/bands` and updating existing ones?

Comment: Well I'm doing this in the simulator and it just says "Simulator write denied". I first noticed it in my developer console where it just said "Permission denied" kind of thing

Comment: @StevieStar were you logged as an authenticated user while attempting that? If there's no need for authentication to add new bands I would change the `".write": "!data.exists() && auth != null",` inside `bands` to `".write": "!data.exists()",`

Comment: In the Firebase console / dashboard while viewing Database -> Rules, there is a Simulator button in the upper right that let's you see the results of attempting to read or write to a specified location, as either authenticated or unauthenticated user. I'm assuming that when you wrote in the earlier comment "Simulator write denied" you're talking about an Android / iOS simulator and not the one I'm referring to.

Comment: Hey @PatNeedham, when I am talking about the simulator, I'm referring to the Firebase console simulator. And unfortunately, I do need authentication for users to create bands. The thing that's weird is that what you answered originally works perfectly if bands already exists and need to be updated, but if anyone is trying to create a new band, the permission gets denied :/

Comment: What's weird is I feel this is a common pattern that should be accounted for. Doesn't `!data.exists()` basically say is there is not any current data at that location when a write operation happens, allow it to happen?